# What is the maximum intensity you can concentrate sunlight?

Tags: optics

I'm trying to figure out what is the maximum possible amount of watts that you can squeeze into a $m^2$ by concentrating sunlight.

[This similar answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/175732/by-what-maximum-amount-can-we-concentrate-sunlight) explains how 42600x is the maximum amount we can concentrate sunlight. And $1000 W/m^2$ is the average intensity of sunlight you can assume on most days.

Does that mean that $42600000 W/m^2$, which results from multiplying the two above numbers, is the maximum intensity concentrated sunlight can achieve?

As a follow up question, how close to achieving this are we in real life? What is the solar intensity currently reached by some of the solar furnaces, like the [Odeillo solar furnace in France](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Odeillo_solar_furnace)?

Comment: the answer is "etendue"  .  Read up on that important rule of optics.

Comment: The web page that you cited for Odeillo says that their mirros shine the equivalent of 10,000 suns onto the target.

Answer (score 1):

The highest temperature you can possibly reach by this method is the temperature of the *source*. Net heat flux per unit area is a different matter.

Comment: Does this mean you can reach a heat flux that exceeds the 42600x limit on concentrating sunlight?

Comment: I do not know how to calculate the maximum possible heat flux.